# What happen when same phase is applied to both MT1 and MT2 of an AC triac

Tags: triac

If same phase is applied to both MT1 and MT2 of an AC triac while it is OFF, will it spoil the Triac? Eg. BTA16.

**Context**

BTA16 along with MOC3021 is being used to control a 220V AC appliance using a micro-controller. There is a scenario where the appliance can get direct supply(through a parallel switch) which in-turn would feed phase back to the triac's output. Is this condition safe? Will is cause any issues with the triac functioning?

Comment: what do you mean "while its gate is zero"?

Comment: @Jasen When no current is applied to the gate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAIEve.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The scenario: SW1 can bypass TRI1.*

If this is the circuit in question it should be clear that closing SW1 poses no threat to the parallel triac switching circuit as all points on it will be at the same potential, that of 'L'.

---

From the comments:

> I hope no issues would happen under any scenarios? i.e Triac ON / OFF and then switched turned ON.

- If triac is off when SW1 is closed then the voltage across the triac changes from full mains voltage to zero. No problem.
- If triac is turned on at the time the switch is opened a couple of things can happen:

  - A zero-cross opto-isolator will wait until the next zero-cross before turning on. (See my article [Opto-triacs, solid-state relays (SSR), zero-cross and how they work](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/) for more on this.)
  - A regular opto-isolator will keep the circuit on if the LED is lit.

Comment: I hope no issues would happen under any scenarios? i.e Triac ON / OFF and then switched turned ON.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: For scenario 2, I hope it won't impact the circuit or components apart from creating a flicker(may not be noticeable though) which may occur due to a zero cross opto?

Comment: I really can't comment on that because there are no details about the load in your question.

Answer (score 0):

No damage.

If no voltage is present across the MT1 MT2 no current flows and the triac turns off (if it was on)

If in this state, no current flows through the gate the triac is ldle, no current flows, no energy enters the triac, no damage can occur.

Having both MT1 and MT2 connected to the same phase and the gate connected to ground would be another thing entirely, a high current would flow through the gate and the triac would be damaged.

Answer (score 0):

> If same phase is applied to both MT1 and MT2 of an AC triac while its
>   gate is zero, will it spoil the Triac?

The gate impedance to either M1 or M2 is that of a forward biased diode so, if the gate is at zero (presumably you mean 0 volts or ground) and, you apply much more than a volt to either M1 or M2 (or both) then you will destroy the device.

If you mean that the gate is open circuit (i.e. no current flowing into the gate) then you'll be fine.

Comment: I have added more context to the question. Please see the edits.

Comment: A triac is bidirectional and therefore either M1 or M2 can be used as an output. If you are now adding other words, to make sure there is no ambiguity, post a schematic of precisely what you mean circuit wise.

Comment: I couldn't add the circuit due to some browser issue and hence added the context. Looks like @Transistor have added a circuit which explains my scenario.